# How do I run a service method periodically?

Tags: android, android-service

I've an android service running, but I want to execute a specific service method every X hours to update data. What's the best aproach to do this without wasting android resources?

Comment: Why don't you just start the service once and then add a timer or make the thread sleep for the amount of time you like?

Comment: This would require that the service process executes *always*. For hours. This is not resource effective.

Comment: Thanks! I'm learning, i'll search how to add timer. Any suggest?

Answer (score 8):

Look into the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Clarification: since you want the service method to run with hourly intervals, you do not want to keep your service process running all this time. By using the `AlarmManager`, the OS can kill the service when it is not needed, and then bring it up to execute the method when it is time.

Comment: What if the intervals are a matter of minutes ? Is it a good idea to use the AlarmManager ? Or better make the thread called by the service sleep for few minutes ?

Comment: @Leeeeeeelo - for efficiency, with small intervals (less than 10-15 minutes), you should not go with AlarmManager. There are discussions on that elsewhere on SO, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434056/how-to-run-a-method-every-x-seconds