# How to run a method every X seconds

Tags: android, timer, nstimer

I'm developing an Android 2.3.3 application and I need to run a method every **X seconds**.

In iOS, I have [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer), but in Android I don't know what to use.

Someone have recommend me [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html); another recommend me [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) but I don't know which method fits better with [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer).

This is the code I want to implement in Android:

```
timer2 = [
    NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0f/20.0f)
    target:self
    selector:@selector(loopTask)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES
];

timer1 = [
    NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0f/4.0f)
    target:self
    selector:@selector(isFree)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES
];
```

I need something what works like [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer).

What do you recommend me?

Comment: Define "the best one". In what way do you want it to be the best?

Comment: I don't know which method fits better with NSTimer.

Comment: @VansFannel How long of an interval are you wanting?

Comment: I've updated the question with details about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242268/repeat-a-task-with-a-time-delay, is similar to this one, and has a great answer.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

The solution you will use really depends on how long you need to wait between each execution of your function.

If you are waiting for longer than 10 minutes, I would suggest using `AlarmManager`.

```java
// Some time when you want to run
Date when = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

try {
    Intent someIntent = new Intent(someContext, MyReceiver.class); // intent to be launched

    // Note: this could be getActivity if you want to launch an activity
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context,
        0, // id (optional)
        someIntent, // intent to launch
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT // PendingIntent flag
    );

    AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(
        Context.ALARM_SERVICE
    );

    alarms.setRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        when.getTime(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,
        pendingIntent
    );
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Once you have broadcasted the above `Intent`, you can receive your `Intent` by implementing a `BroadcastReceiver`. Note that this will need to be registered either in your application manifest or via the `context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);` method. [For more information on `BroadcastReceiver`'s please refer to the official documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

```java
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        System.out.println("MyReceiver: here!") // Do your work here
    }
}
```

If you are waiting for shorter than 10 minutes then I would suggest using a `Handler`.

```java
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final int delay = 1000; // 1000 milliseconds == 1 second

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("myHandler: here!"); // Do your work here
        handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);
```

Comment: Why different suggestions depending on the time delay?

Comment: Efficiency, In the AlarmManager docs it states that it should not be used for any small interval repetitive task.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg in the [AlarmManager docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) it states that Handler is the preffered and more effecient method to use for short ticks: "Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler."

Comment: But, I need to run a method in the same Activity that has launch the AlarmManager. How can I do that?

Comment: Answer Revised, also if you need it within an activity it would probably be better and easier to use a handler. You could use like the example i posted or even create a "Timer" class to wrap this functionality.

Comment: In here: `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES` , I actually need it to be only 1 MINUTE, how do i set it ?

Comment: How would you stop this handler `h` after a condition?

Comment: @ahmadalibaloch from within the runnable you can do ```h.removeCallbacks(this);```, else you need to maintain a reference to the runnable to be able to remove it. If the second is desired the method posted here might not be your best route.

Comment: Handler solution worked perfectly on Xamarin.Android aswell, doing so : `Action action = NameOfTheCallbackMethod;
 h.PostDelayed(action, 1000);`

Comment: Will this form of continual recursion not eventually lead to stack overflow?

Comment: @AndrewS no, since this is not method/call stack recursion. What this is doing is simply reusing the same callback to post and then receive delayed(off a separate thread) message events.

Answer (score 135):

Use Timer for every second...

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //your method
    }
}, 0, 1000);//put here time 1000 milliseconds=1 second
```

Comment: I've updated the question with details about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Don't use Timer (http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/), use Handler or ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: @AppiDevo Link seems dead, try https://web.archive.org/web/20200131001301/http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/

Answer (score 96):

You can please try this code to call the handler every 15 seconds via onResume() and stop it when the activity is not visible, via onPause().

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable;
int delay = 15*1000; //Delay for 15 seconds.  One second = 1000 milliseconds.


@Override
protected void onResume() {
   //start handler as activity become visible

    handler.postDelayed( runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //do something

            handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
        }
    }, delay);

    super.onResume();
}

// If onPause() is not included the threads will double up when you 
// reload the activity 

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable); //stop handler when activity not visible
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 20):

If you are familiar with RxJava, you can use Observable.interval(), which is pretty neat.

```
Observable.interval(60, TimeUnits.SECONDS)
          .flatMap(new Function<Long, ObservableSource<String>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<String> apply(@NonNull Long aLong) throws Exception {
                    return getDataObservable(); //Where you pull your data
                }
            });
```

The downside of this is that you have to architect polling your data in a different way. However, there are a lot of benefits to the Reactive Programming way:

1. Instead of controlling your data via a callback, you create a stream of data that you subscribe to. This separates the concern of "polling data" logic and "populating UI with your data" logic so that you do not mix your "data source" code and your UI code.
2. With RxAndroid, you can handle threads in just 2 lines of code.

   ```
   Observable.interval(60, TimeUnits.SECONDS)
         .flatMap(...) // polling data code
         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) // poll data on a background thread
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // populate UI on main thread
         .subscribe(...); // your UI code
   ```

Please check out RxJava. It has a high learning curve but it will make handling asynchronous calls in Android so much easier and cleaner.

Answer (score 14):

With Kotlin, we can now make a generic function for this!

```
fun repeatDelayed(delay: Long, action: () -> Unit): Handler {
    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    handler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            action()
            handler.postDelayed(this, delay)
        }
    }, delay)
    return handler
}
```

And to use, just do:

```
val delay = 1000L
repeatDelayed(delay) {
    myRepeatedFunction()
}
```

To cancel the repeating function:

```
val myHandler = repeatDelayed(1000L) {
    myRepeatedFunction()
}
myHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
```

Remember to cancel any ongoing Runnables that aren't relevant when the app isn't visible (such as periodic UI updates) in onStop:

```
override fun onStop() {
    myHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            txtcounter.setText(" " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        }

        public void onFinish() {

            txtcounter.setText(" TimeOut  ");
            Main2Activity.ShowPayment = false;
            EventBus.getDefault().post("go-main");

        }

    }.start();
```

Comment: Do not post code only answer. Please [edit] your answer and add some explanation.

Comment: Add information

Answer (score 2):

Here I used a thread in onCreate() an Activity repeatly, timer does not allow everything in some cases Thread is the solution

```
     Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);  //1000ms = 1 sec
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("sam", MODE_PRIVATE);
                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            String json = mPrefs.getString("chat_list", "");
                            GelenMesajlar model = gson.fromJson(json, GelenMesajlar.class);
                            String sam = "";

                            ChatAdapter adapter = new ChatAdapter(Chat.this, model.getData());
                            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                           // listview.setStackFromBottom(true);
                          //  Util.showMessage(Chat.this,"Merhabalar");
                        }
                    });

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    t.start();
```

In case it needed it can be stoped by

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Thread.interrupted();
    //t.interrupted();
}
```

Comment: please describe the situation when my answer will not work

Comment: Hello Umar. I needed a circle whole time that app is alive, Handler made repetition alive while activity is alive but I need the circle while I was able to visit other activities too. So thread is solution in this way sure it also has its struggle.

Answer (score 2):

I do it this way and it works fine (the code is written in **Kotlin**):

```
private lateinit var runnable: Runnable

private var handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

private val repeatPeriod: Long = 10000
```

Then reinit the runnable from inside your function

```
runnable = Runnable {

    // Your code goes here

    handler.postDelayed(runnable, repeatPeriod)

}

handler.postDelayed(runnable, repeatPeriod)
```

Note that if you don't **postDelay** twice the **handler**, the loop is not going to be intinity!

Answer (score 1):

In **Kotlin**, you can do it this way with a Runnable:

```
private lateinit var runnable: Runnable
private var handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
private val interval: Long = 1000
private var isRunning = false
```

```
val runnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        // Do something every second
        function()
        // Call your runnable again after interval
      handler?.postDelayed(runnable(this, interval))
    }
}
    
// Call your function once
if (!isRunning) {
    handler?.postDelayed(runnable, interval)
    isRunning = true
}

// Remove your repeatedly called function
if (isRunning) {
    handler?.removeCallbacks(runnable)
    isRunning = false
}
```