# Execute function after 5 seconds in Android

Tags: java, android, timer

I am new in android development and now my launcher activity show only 5 seconds and after that I want to check the user is logged in or not function and perform the actions.

here is my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    exactPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ExactPreference",MODE_PRIVATE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_landing_page);

    session = exactPreferences.getString(Model.getSingleton().SHARED_SESSION_ID,null);
    Log.i("Session Id",session);
        displayData(); // I want to perform this function after 5 seconds.
}


private void displayData() {
    if(session.equals("")){
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(LandingPage.this,
                LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        Log.i("User Logged In", "False");
    }
    else
    {
        Intent objIntent = new Intent(LandingPage.this,
                IndexPageActivity.class);
        startActivity(objIntent);
        Log.i("User Logged In", "True");
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a CountDownTimer.

Comment: Use PostDelayed Handler

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434056/how-to-run-a-method-every-x-seconds

Answer (score 136, accepted):

**Updated:**
Using Kotin Couroutines:

```
val job = scope.launch {
   delay(5000)
   displayData();
 }
```

Here you can use GlobalScope, viewmodelScope, or lifecycleScope. To cancel this job you can call the cancel method.

```
job.cancel()
```

You can use the Handler to add some delay.Call the method `displayData()` as below so that it will be executed after 5 seconds.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          displayData();
        }
    }, 5000);
```

**Note :** Do not use the threads like  `Thread.sleep(5000);` because it will block your UI and and makes it irresponsive.

Comment: also remove runnable onPause() and add runnable onResume().

Comment: handler is deprecated now

Answer (score 7):

Since, Handler is now deprecated so use this code :

```
 new Handler(Looper.myLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         //do what you want 
     }
 }, 5000);
```

Comment: Since which SDK version it is being deprecated?

Comment: @HX_unbanned only the default constructor is deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

Use a CountDownTimer

```
// There's a TextView txtCount in Main Activity

final int secs = 5;
new CountDownTimer((secs +1) * 1000, 1000) // Wait 5 secs, tick every 1 sec
{
    @Override
    public final void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        txtCount.setText("" + (int) (millisUntilFinished * .001f));
    }
    @Override
    public final void onFinish()
    {
        txtCount.setText("GO!");
        finish();
        // Time's up - Start the Login Activity
        final Intent tnt =
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(tnt);
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 6):

Assign **millisDelayTime** variable with the milliseconds you desire to cause a delay. **mActivity** is an object of **Activity** for providing Application Context. In your case **millisDelayTime** should be initialized with 5000

```
mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
    public void run() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
             //your code here
       }
    }, millisDelayTime);
  }
});
```

Comment: is it called every 5000ms or it just called after delay 5000 ms ? @mushahid

Comment: Whenever the runOnUiThread gets called, a 5000ms delay happens.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, code create CountDownTimer with one tick

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 5000)
{
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
    }

    public void onFinish()
    {
        displayData();
    }
};
timer.start();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
long delay = 1000;
long period = 50000;
Timer task = new Timer();
task.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getDriver(sessionManager.getKEY(), ride_id);
    }
}, delay, period);
```

Comment: not a usable ..did you tried it yourself or just copied pasted here?

Comment: @satyaprakash i have tried it, and it works for me... why you have given negative vote?

Comment: Because you can't pass a integer parameter in scheduleAtFixedRate which accepts a TIMEUNIT type of parameter(last parameter as periods).

Comment: @satyaprakash Brother scheduleAtFixedRate() method accept three parameter. 1. task 2. delay 3. period.  you can also refer to this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/timer_scheduleatfixedrate_delay.htm . delay and period only accepts integer parameter. I don't know where you are finding me wrong.

Comment: see this developer site:- https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: @satyaprakash ok my bad, changed the data type. I think it is correct now?

Comment: No it is not it's still in long, "IT ACCEPT TIMEUNIT(enum) TYPE OF PERIOD"

Answer (score 4):

For kotlin way

```
Handler().postDelayed({
        //do something
    }, 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option to achieve this is using a [**Handler**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html):

```
int TIME = 5000; //5000 ms (5 Seconds)

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        function(); //call function!

    }
}, TIME);
```

Answer (score 0):

When possible, try to avoid using postDelayed. It is a bad practice, since it can lose the reference to the objects that you want to draw on your screen and cause a NPE. Use a Handler instead. First of all, create a global variable Handler in which you will have to "handle" the logic for your code. Do so by using the function handleMessage.

```
Handler  handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(msg.what == 1){
            // your code here
        }
    }
};
```

Then, wherever you want to execute it, just call the function:

```
// 1 is the ID of your process
handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1, 5000);
```

Please remember that in the onDestroyView method (in a Fragment) or the onDestroy (in an Activity) you will have to call

```
    handler.removeMessages(1)
```