# How to delay the execution of a method without delaying the whole thread knowing that I can't (or don't know how to) make different threads?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So, I have a program which, when pressing a button, changes an image src programmatically (with a method I made) then calls another method I made, but I want for the second method to be called after a delay of a few seconds. I already tried `Thread.sleep(5000)`, `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2)`, and `wait()` but all of these pauses the whole program hindering the change of the image src.

Here is the code :

```
public void onButtonClickListenerGoHit(int buttonId) {
    button_test = findViewById(buttonId);
    button_test.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    changeImage(R.id.imageView2, R.drawable.lodef);
                    gameOver();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

So what I want is for the `gameOver()` to be called a few seconds after `changeImage()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a method every X seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434056/how-to-run-a-method-every-x-seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Kotlin example

```
Handler().postDelayed({
  // call your method
}, 1000 /*delay in milliseconds*/)
```

java

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run () {
   // make operation on UI - on example
   // on progress bar.
 }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks but I actually use Java. Do you know if there is an equivalent ?

Comment: Are you kidding me? Updated

Comment: Thanks (sorry my Java knowledge is quite low)

Comment: If it's correct answer, please choose my answer as correct one

Comment: Thanks a lot, I literally spent the whole day on this part of my program.