# How to use a handler to loop an if statement every 20 seconds

Tags: java, android-studio

Hi I have been having issues using the handler (I have used nearly every single example in any thread about looping stuff using handler)to loop a if statement that I need to rerun every 20 secs, I'm very new to java, and please ignore my stupid toast messages, could someone edit it so it will rerun the code every 20 seconds, Thanks in advance

```
DisplayManager dm = (DisplayManager) getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);

for (final Display display : dm.getDisplays()) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "for loop reached", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    int state = display.getState();
    String StateString = Integer.toString(state);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, StateString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (display.getState() == 1) {
        String command = "dumpsys deviceidle force-idle deep";
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "not failed yayay", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        TextView tv9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
        tv9.setText("The screen was turned off");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The screen is offfffffffff lolol", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The screen is on lolol", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far ? You have almost all the answer in your question 'loop' :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434056/how-to-run-a-method-every-x-seconds, I have used this link and a few more and When i insert my code into the "put your code here" my app just crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a second example:

```
package samples;

public class Emitter2 {
    public static final int MS_IN_SEC = 1000;

    public static final int[] DELAYS = { 1, 3, 4, 5, 7 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Emitter[] emitters = new Emitter[ DELAYS.length ];
        Thread[] emitterThreads = new Thread[ DELAYS.length ];

        for ( int emitterNo = 0; emitterNo < DELAYS.length; emitterNo++ ) {
            int delay = DELAYS[emitterNo];
            System.out.println("main: Emitter [ " + emitterNo + " ] has delay [ " + delay + " s ]");
            Emitter emitter = newEmitter(MS_IN_SEC * delay);
            emitters[emitterNo] = emitter;
            emitterThreads[emitterNo] = new Thread(emitter);
        }

        System.out.println("main: Starting emitters");
        for ( int emitterNo = 0; emitterNo < DELAYS.length; emitterNo++ ) {
            emitterThreads[emitterNo].start();
        }
        System.out.println("main: Started emitters");

        System.out.println("main: Running emitters for 50s");
        sleep("main", MS_IN_SEC * 50);
        System.out.println("main: Completed running emitters for 50s");

        System.out.println("main: Requesting emitters to stop");
        for ( int emitterNo = 0; emitterNo < DELAYS.length; emitterNo++ ) {
            emitters[emitterNo].requestStop();
        }
        System.out.println("main: Requested emitters to stop");

        System.out.println("main: Waiting for emitters to stop");
        for ( int emitterNo = 0; emitterNo < DELAYS.length; emitterNo++ ) {
            try {
                emitterThreads[emitterNo].join();
            } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                System.out.println("main: Interrupted waiting for emitter to stop");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("main: Waited for emitters to stop");
    }

    public static boolean sleep(String threadName, int mSec) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(mSec);
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            System.out.println(threadName + ": Interrupted on delay of [ " + mSec + " ms ]!");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public interface Emitter extends Runnable {
        void requestStop();
        boolean getStopped();
    }

    public static Emitter newEmitter(int delayMs) {
        return new Emitter() {
            private final String emitterName = "emitter" + delayMs;
            private boolean stopped;

            public synchronized void requestStop() {
                stopped= true;
            }

            public synchronized boolean getStopped() {
                return stopped;
            }

            public void run() {
                int counter = 0;
                while ( !getStopped() ) {
                    System.out.println(emitterName + ": Count [ " + counter + " ]");
                    counter++;

                    if ( !sleep(emitterName, delayMs) ) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(emitterName + ": Stopped at count [ " + counter + " ]");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is not entirely clear.  Here are some examples of running tasks at fixed delays in a separate thread.  There are a lot of different ways to code this sort of example; this example is just one of many.

Example 1 Output:

```
main: Starting emitter with a delay of 5s
main: Started emitter
main: Running emitter for 50s
emitter: Count [ 0 ]
emitter: Count [ 1 ]
emitter: Count [ 2 ]
emitter: Count [ 3 ]
emitter: Count [ 4 ]
emitter: Count [ 5 ]
emitter: Count [ 6 ]
emitter: Count [ 7 ]
emitter: Count [ 8 ]
emitter: Count [ 9 ]
main: Completed running emitter for 50s
main: Stopping emitter
emitter: Stopped at count [ 10 ]
main: Stopped emitter
```

Example 1:

```
package samples;

public class Emitter1 {
    public static final int MS_IN_SEC = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Emitter emitter = newEmitter(MS_IN_SEC * 5);
        Thread emitterThread = new Thread(emitter);

        System.out.println("main: Starting emitter with a delay of 5s");
        emitterThread.start();
        System.out.println("main: Started emitter");

        System.out.println("main: Running emitter for 50s");
        sleep("main", MS_IN_SEC * 50);
        System.out.println("main: Completed running emitter for 50s");

        System.out.println("main: Stopping emitter");

        emitter.requestStop();
        try {
            emitterThread.join();
            System.out.println("main: Stopped emitter");
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            System.out.println("main: Interrupted waiting for emitter to finish");
        }

    }

    public static boolean sleep(String threadName, int mSec) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(mSec);
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            System.out.println(threadName + ": Interrupted on delay of [ " + mSec + " ms ]!");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public interface Emitter extends Runnable {
        void requestStop();
        boolean getStopped();
    }

    public static Emitter newEmitter(int delayMs) {
        return new Emitter() {
            private boolean stopped;

            public synchronized void requestStop() {
                stopped= true;
            }

            public synchronized boolean getStopped() {
                return stopped;
            }

            public void run() {
                int counter = 0;
                while ( !getStopped() ) {
                    System.out.println("emitter: Count [ " + counter + " ]");
                    counter++;

                    if ( !sleep("emitter", delayMs) ) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("emitter: Stopped at count [ " + counter + " ]");
            }
        };
    }
}
```