# How to show dialog after an hour in android

Tags: java, android

I have an dialog which I wanted to show the dialog after every hour in android, its like Scheduled time, is this possible to do?

```
 Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.collect_points);
            dialog.findViewById(R.id.collect_point_everyday).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11434143/11647620

Comment: Use [`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) Its the right way to do it. 
Use [`setExactAndAllowWhileIdle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) to set the Alarm .

Comment: You need to handle few things though.

1. If you need to show dialog even if App is closed you gotta open an Activity . If not and you want to postponed it further till next Hour the you can save a value in `SharedPreference` and whenever your Activity gets open you check the value  in `SharedPreference` and show the Dialog if needed. If you do not want to postponed it then do nothing .

2. On every Alarm call you need to set Subsequent Alarm for next Hour.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`service`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) for this task.
you can look into this answer [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918571/how-to-display-a-dialog-from-a-service).