# How to Automatically Update ProgressBar in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I am making a android app and for that I want to update my progressBar Automatically at each second but it isn't working like that.Instead it's calling the function only once .

```
    private int progress=1;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private boolean mTimerRunning=true;
    private long mTimeLeft=START;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

private void startTimer(){
        countDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeft,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                mTimeLeft=l;
                updateText();
                updateProgressBar();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        }.start();
        mTimerRunning=true;
        button.setText("Pause");



    }
    private void updateText(){
            int minutes=(int) (mTimeLeft/1000)/60;
        int seconds=(int) (mTimeLeft/1000)%60;

        String timeLeft=String.format("%02d:%02d",minutes,seconds);
        textView.setText(timeLeft);
    }

    private void updateProgressBar()
    {

          progressBar.setProgress(progress+1);
    }
```

Comment: Print mTimeLeft 's value, maybe it's not milliseconds.

Comment: Your answer is probably here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11434143/2027232

Comment: Use nested `Handler.postDelayed()` methods to update the progressbar every second